# Multi Module Spring Boot Application : how do i add timestamp to jar file in each module outputs the "jar"

Tags: spring-boot, maven, timestamp

I have pom.xml from the parent and the other 2 modules. I am trying to add a timestamp like E-Version-1.0.001-06-15-2022-09-32.jar

All my modules should output files with time stamps. I have a hard time.

Tried possible solutions:

Added properties and final name in build tag, This builds 1 module but the remaining module fails?
'''

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <outputFolder>C:/AutomationTestReports/${project.name}/Execution_(${timestamp})</outputFolder>
</properties>
<build>
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>
</build>
```

'''
**Parent pom.xml**

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Spring IO Platform is the parent of the generated application to
    be able to use Spring Boot and all its default configuration -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>sample.multimodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample.multimodule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Parent - Pom Aggregator</name>
    <description>This pom is a maven aggregator that contains all application modules. Also, include all
    common dependencies needed by more than one module. Dependencies are defined without version because
    this project has defined Spring IO Platform as parent.</description>

    <properties>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>

    <modules>
      <module>model</module>
      <module>repository</module>
      <module>service-api</module>
      <module>service-impl</module>
      <module>application</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>

      <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
      <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

'''

Application Module Pom.xml

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>sample.multimodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample.multimodule</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>sample.multimodule.application</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Project Module - Application</name>
   
    <dependencies>

      <!-- Project modules -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>sample.multimodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample.multimodule.service.impl</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
              <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot plugins -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

'''

Sevice Module pom.xml

'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>sample.multimodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample.multimodule</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>sample.multimodule.service.impl</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Project Module - Service Implementation</name>
    <description>Module that contains services implementation defined on Service API module. Depends of Repository Module and 
    Service API Module.</description>    

    <dependencies>

      <!-- Project Modules -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>sample.multimodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample.multimodule.repository</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>sample.multimodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample.multimodule.service.api</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    
</project>
```

'''

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Please explain in depth: `All my modules should output files with time stamps. I have a hard time` why do you need that as already @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen mentioned... The definition of `<finalName>...</finalName>` will not work because it's only for the `target` directory....